# Does this proof make sense(The well-ordering principle for N)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

I need to explain the proof given by Des McHale in his "The well-ordering principle for N". I was hoping you could tell me if it makes sense and what else I could add to it. This is what I have so far:

"
In his paper, Des MacHale talks about the Well-Ordering Principle for $\mathbb{N}$. This is a different method to solving proofs. He says that this is a less talked about tool in the mathematicians belt, but is useful to know. He goes on to say that it "appears to be a more natural approach than induction." Using the Well Ordering Principle, also known as WOP, he goes on to solve and prove many theorems. One such theorem that he proves is that $\sqrt2\notin\mathbb{N}$. He uses WOP as a proof for this. In this paper we will attempt to use WOP as well to prove that $\sqrt3\notin\mathbb{Q}$. To put this in English, we want to prove that the square root of three is not a rational number.

Similar to the theorem proving that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, to prove that $\sqrt{3}$ is also irrational, it needs to be proven that there is no pair of positive integers (a,b) where $(a/b)^2 = 3$.

Set S can be a set of pairs of integers (a,b) where $(a/b)^2 = 3$

If S is non-empty, according to the Well Ordering Principle, S has to have at least one element c = a + b where $a^2 = 3b^2$.

When $a^2$ is divided by 3, and if $a = 3k + 1$ is odd, $a^2 = 9k^2 + 6k + 1$ which is odd, creating a contradiction.

Following, $a = 3k$ is even where $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Next, $(3k)^2 = 9k^2 = 3b^2$ so $b^2 = 3k$ is even.

Following our argument before, $b = 2s$ is even too where $s\in\mathbb{N}$.

Because $a^2 = 3b^2$, we have $(3k)^2 = 3(2s)^2$ and then $k^2 = 2s^2$.

However, $a + b = 2(k+s)$, so $k + s < a + b$ which is a contradiction.

This contradiction shows that the set S is empty and therefore there is no pair of positive integers (a,b) where $(a/b)^2 = 3$.

This proves that $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational.

"

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: "If S is non-empty, according to the Well Ordering Principle, S has to have at least one element" does it really say that? That's crazy - saying S is nonempty **means** that S has at least one element! WOP seems totally irrelevant to the proof you give here. (WOP says any nonempty subset of $\Bbb N$ has a smallest element. Since S is not a subset of $\Bbb N$ this says nothing about S.)

Comment: If $S$ is a set of pairs of integers, then it doesn't have an element "$c = a+b$".

Answer (score 1):

I think you are following the argument for $\sqrt{2}$ word for word, just substituting $3$ for $2$ without thinking. This assertion

> When $a^2$ is divided by $3$, and if $a=3k+1$ is odd, $a^2=9k^2+6k + 1$ which is
> odd, creating a contradiction.

makes no sense. What you know from the preceding line is that $3$ divides $a^2$. You then start thinking about whether $a$ is odd or even, and say it can't be the odd number $3k+1$. But that number need not be odd - what if $k$ were $5$? The real reason $a$ can't be $3k+1$ is that its square $ 9k^2+6k_1$ is not a multiple of $3$. Whether it's odd or even is irrelevant.

You need to think about what form $a$ might have. Odd and even are irrelevant in this argument.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I'm starting to understand this a little bit more. Your explanation helps a great deal.

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid that the argument has a number of problems. First of all, it does not in fact use the well-ordering principle at all. The well-ordering principle says that every non-empty set of non-negative integers has a smallest element; your $S$ is not a set of integers at all. But there are quite a few other problems, so I’ll go through it in detail.

> Set S can be a set of pairs of integers (a,b) where $(a/b)^2 = 3$
>
> If S is non-empty, according to the Well Ordering Principle, S has to have at least one element c = a + b where $a^2 = 3b^2$.

You defined $S$ to be a set of **pairs** of integers, and now you’re saying that a single integer $c$ is an element of $S$; this is impossible. You are actually dealing with **two** sets here. Let $P$ be the set of ordered pairs $\langle a,b\rangle$ of **positive** integers such that $(a/b)^2=3$. Then let $S=\{a+b:\langle a,b\rangle\in P\}$; now $S$ really **is** a set of positive integers, so we **can** apply the well-ordering principle to it. Specifically, if $P$ is not empty, then clearly $S$ is non-empty, and we can let $c$ be the smallest element of $S$. The definition of $S$ then ensures that there is a pair $\langle a,b\rangle\in P$ such that $c=a+b$.

> When $a^2$ is divided by 3, and if $a = 3k + 1$ is odd, $a^2 = 9k^2 + 6k + 1$ which is odd, creating a contradiction.

This does not make sense as English. A sentence that starts *When $a^2$ is divided by $3$* should continue by telling us what happens when $a^2$ is divided by $3$; yours does not. What you should be saying here is that since $a^2=3b^2$, we know that $a^2$ is **divisible** by $3$. What happens when we try to divide $a$ by $3$? There are $3$ possibilities: $a$ is divisible by $3$, in which case there is a positive integer $k$ such that $a=3k$; there is a remainder of $1$ when we divide $a$ by $3$, in which case $a=3k+1$ for some positive integer $k$; or there is a remainder of $2$ when we divide $a$ by $3$, in which case $a=3k+2$ for some positive integer $k$. Since your goal is to show that $a$ is a multiple of $3$, you need to eliminate both of the last two possibilities, not just one of them.

Whether or not $3k+1$ is odd depends entirely on $k$: $3k+1$ is odd if $k$ is even, and even if $k$ is odd. I suspect that you were following the proof for $\sqrt2$ without paying enough attention to what is actually going on. The even and odd cases in that proof correspond to the three cases $a=3k$, $a=3k+1$, and $a=3k+2$ in this proof.

What you mean is that if $a=3k+1$, then $$a^2=9k^2+6k+1=3(3k^2+2k)+1\,,$$ which is not divisible by $3$; this is impossible, so $a$ does not leave a remainder of $1$ when divided by $3$. Similarly, if $a=3k+2$, then

$$a^2=9k^2+12k+4=3(3k^2+4k+1)+1\,;$$

this is not divisible by $3$, so this case can also be ruled out, and we conclude that $a=3k$ for some positive integer $k$:

> Following, $a = 3k$ is even where $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Again, this has nothing to do with being even or odd; the point is that $a$ is divisible by $3$.

> Next, $(3k)^2 = 9k^2 = 3b^2$ so $b^2 = 3k$ is even.

This has the same problem: $b^2$ may or may not be even, since it is even if and only if $k$ is even, and we know nothing about $k$. The point here is that $b^2$ is divisible by $3$, not by $2$ as in the proof for $\sqrt2$.

> Following our argument before, $b = 2s$ is even too where $s\in\mathbb{N}$.

And here you’ve simply copied from the proof for $\sqrt2$ in a way that makes no sense and does you no good.

We just showed that if $a^2$ is divisible by $3$, so is $a$. It is **that** argument that we want to use again, this time to show that since $b^2$ is divisible by $3$, so is $b$. We’ve done it once, with $a$, so we can certainly do it again with $b$ to show that $b=\color{red}3s$ (not $2s$) for some positive integer $s$: it’s just a matter of changing every $a$ to $b$ and every $k$ to $s$. This is clear enough that we don’t need to write out the details.

> Because $a^2 = 3b^2$, we have $(3k)^2 = 3(2s)^2$ and then $k^2 = 2s^2$.

No, because $a^2=3b^2$ we have $(3k)^2=3(\color{red}3s)^2$, and hence $k^2=\color{red}3s^2$.

> However, $a + b = 2(k+s)$, so $k + s < a + b$ which is a contradiction.

Here again you’re copying from the $\sqrt2$ without paying enough attention to the algebra that you’re doing. In fact $a+b=\color{red}3k+\color{red}3s=\color{red}3(k+s)$. Of course this still lets you conclude that $k+s<a+b=c$. The pair $\langle k,s\rangle$ is in $P$, so $k+s\in S$, but we’ve just shown that $k+s<c$, where $c$ is the smallest member of $S$. This is plainly impossible, so we conclude that $S$ is empty, and therefore $P$ is also empty — i.e., $\sqrt3$ is irrational.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I really appreciate that you replied with so much detail. I am starting to understand this more.

Comment: @PaulSteiner: You’re very welcome.